# Какое событие происходит при скроллинге вниз и вверх?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При скролле вниз белая тень должна появляться сверху, а снизу исчезать и наоборот.

Уточню вопрос:
1. Если начинаем скроллим вниз появляется класс .bottom-scroll в контейнерt, в котором происходит скрол.
2. Если начинаем крутить вверх, появляется класс .top-scroll, при этом исчезает класс .bottom-scroll

```js
(function($) {
      $(window).load(function() {
        $(".postcard-container").mCustomScrollbar({
          theme: "inset-2-dark",
          setHeight: "100%"
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
a {
  color: #0262a0
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 705px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
.top-panel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #e2fffe
}
.top-panel .wrap {
  height: 155px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center
}
.rating-form {
  padding-top: 20px
}
.rating-form:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: ""
}
.rating-form .total-vote {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
.rating {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end
}
.rating:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: ""
}
.rating label,
.rating>input:checked ~ label {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px
}
.rating:not(:checked)>label,
.rating>input:checked ~ label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked+label:hover ~ label,
.rating>label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover ~ label {
  background: url("http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/star.png") no-repeat
}
.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
.rating:not(:checked)>label {
  background-position: 0 -16px
}
.postcard-area .tab-content {
  border: 1px solid #cbd1d9;
  border-top-width: 0
}
.postcard-area .tab-content .tab-pane {
  height: 560px;
  padding: 40px 10px 40px 0
}
.postcard-area .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  background-color: #00549f;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff
}
.postcard-area .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #55595c
}
.postcard-area .nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: #373a3c
}
.postcard-area .nav-tabs .nav-link:focus {
  outline: none
}
.postcard-area .nav-tabs .nav-item+.nav-item {
  margin-left: 0
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container {
  position: relative
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container img {
  max-width: 170px
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  content: '';
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #fff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0)
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul {
  margin: 0 0 -30px 35px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: ""
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li {
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
  margin: 0 0 30px 15px;
  float: left;
  position: relative
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li label {
  position: relative
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li label:before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li label:before,
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li input {
  display: none
}
.postcard-area .postcard-container ul li input:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #e1005d
}
.notification-block {
  padding: 25px 0
}
.notification-block .notification {
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 23px;
  position: relative
}
.notification-block .notification[data-count]:not([data-count='']):after {
  background-color: #ff3e2c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-count);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 .4em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 15px;
  top: -8px;
  right: -10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff
}
```

```html
<link href="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<header class="top-panel">
  <div class="wrap">
    <form action="#" class="rating-form">
      <div class="rating">
        <input type="radio" id="star05" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star05" title="5">5</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star04" name="rating" value="4">
        <label for="star04" title="4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star03" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star03" title="3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star02" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star02" title="2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star01" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="star01" title="1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="total-vote"><span class="count">2</span> голоса</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="postcard-area wrap">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#postcard" role="tab">Открытки 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#postcard-second" role="tab">Открытки 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#postcard-third" role="tab">Открытки 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="postcard" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="postcard-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-01">
            <label for="card-01">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/01.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-02">
            <label for="card-02">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/02.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-03">
            <label for="card-03">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/03.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-04">
            <label for="card-04">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/04.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-05">
            <label for="card-05">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/05.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-06">
            <label for="card-06">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/06.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-07">
            <label for="card-07">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/07.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-08">
            <label for="card-08">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/08.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card-09">
            <label for="card-09">
              <img src="http://artlenk.ru/project/avd/images/09.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="postcard-second" role="tabpanel">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="postcard-third" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не проще присобачить DIV поверх элементов с полупрозрачным градиентом в зависимости от ScrollPos?

Comment: уже сделал, это я знал, просто не знаю событие при скроллинге. Еслит скролить вниз то тень переносится вверх, и наоборот.

Comment: У тебя какой то mCustomScrollbar у него должны быть события на изменение Scroll-а.

Comment: вы правы, там довольно подробная конфигурация http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ но никак не могу найти отвечающую за добавление класса когда скроллишь вниз и вверх

Comment: Тебе нужно цеплятся на callbacks:{
    whileScrolling:function(){
      console.log("Scrolling...");
    }
}